# Always encrypted queries with ODBC and Azure Vault

Tags: .net-core, odbc, always-encrypted

I'm trying to select or insert data into a Always Encrypted table in SQL Server using ODBC in a .net core application. So far, I can do it when the keys are auto generated locally (I'm able to save new records through my application) and they encrypt and decrypt correctly, but when I encrypt the database using a key saved to Azure Vault, I'm getting the next errors:

> ERROR [CE269] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error 12038 sending request to https://nameofvault.vault.azure.net:443
>
> ERROR [CE263] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error verifying signature of ECEK.
>
> ERROR [CE202] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The keystore provider AZURE_KEY_VAULT failed to decrypt the ECEK https://nameofvault.vault.azure.net:443/keys/CMKAuto1/currentversionofkey with RSA_OAEP.

I'm connecting to the database using the column encryption setting and authenticating with AppId and Secret, at first I was getting authentication errors (set up was wrong) but now I'm getting this, trying to access my local db

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this error?